# How do I display two div on button click using toggle?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, button, click, toggle

I am developing application in MVC. I have placed one button. I displayed the div while clicking a button. On clicking a button I used toggle to show the div. Now my problem is inside the div I need to display another form or div. Is it possible?

*My code is*

```
if (button_id == "reminder_button") {

            $('.reminder').toggle("slow")
            {

                $('#remdr').appendTo('reminder');

            };
```

*View code:*

```
<div class="remdr" id="remdr" style="display:none">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Reminder", "Appt", FormMethod.Post, new  { id = "rem" }))
    {
 @Html.Label("Reminder Text")
        <input type="text" name="Remtitle" style="width:200px" />

        @Html.Label("Notifications")
        @Html.DropDownList("Reminderlist", new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"))
        <input type="text" name="number" style="width:200px" />
        @Html.DropDownList("Reminder", new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text"))
        <input type="submit" name="reminder" value="Remind me">
        <div id="Addnotification" style="color:blue; font-size:15px">Add Notification</div>

    }
</div>
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: hey ... :) are you from India :)

Comment: Yes.. i am from india @RahulMishra

Comment: Cool .. me too @Nisha  from where  ? Delhi ..Gurgaon..Pune..Banglore

Comment: Yes.. working  in kanyakumari @RahulMishra

Comment: @Nisha  Omg .. i think in kanyakumari their is not such type of work :)

Comment: @Nisha If you are comfortable lets talk here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92346/indiangeeks

Comment: @RahulMishra Bit busy in work